# Subset of query in linq

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

Id like to perform chain query which which looks like this
I've given continent Id and based on this I choose one:

```
    var continent = db.Continent.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == Continent_Id);
```

Then I'd like to find subset of countries from the given continent.
Then I'd like to find subset of the cities from the given countries based on country Id. Any ideas how to do this?
These are my classes:

```
public class Contient
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
}   

public class Country
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int ContientId { get; set; }
}
 public class City
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int CountryId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you need to add some [navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) in your model:

```
public class Continent
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Country> Country{get;set;}//Add this property
}   

public class Country
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int ContinentId { get; set; }

  public virtual Continent Continent{get;set;}//Add this property
  public virtual ICollection<City> Cities{get;set;}//Add this property
}
public class City
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int CountryId { get; set; }
  public virtual Country Country{get;set;}//Add this property
}
```

Then you can run a query like this:

```
var countries= db.Countries.Where(c=>c.ContinentId==Continent_Id);
var cities= countries.SelectMany(c=>c.Cities);
```

And, if you already have the continent, you can also do this:

```
  var continent = db.Continent.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == Continent_Id);
  var countries= continent.Countries;
  var cities= countries.SelectMany(c=>c.Cities);
```

The [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method will flatten the cities related with each country into one sequence.

### Update

I'm going to show you how you can do the same without using the navigation properties in your queries, but I still recommend you need to add them to your model:

```
var continent = db.Continent.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == Continent_Id);
var countries=  db.Countries.Where(c=>c.ContinentId==Continent_Id);
var countriesId=countries.Select(c=>c.Id).ToList();
var cities= db.Cities.Where(c=>countriesId.Contains(c.CountryId));
```

Comment: and what if I can\t change the model?

Comment: Adding those navigation properties is not going to affect your database squema. EF Code First needs at least one navigation property per relationship to create a foreign key constraint in the database, if you don't add at least one, the FK properties will be treated like any other column in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like this

```
Continent[] continents; 
Country[] countries; 
City[] cities;
(...)
int continentId=5; //just a example
```

somewhere in your code then this would suffice:

LINQ-Queries:

```
//Getting Continent
var quContinents = from continent
                   in continents
                   where country.Id == continentId 
                   select continent

//Getting Countries from Continent
var quCountries = from country
                  in countries
                  where country.continentID == continentId
                  select country

//go trough all countries which as been found
foreach(var country in quCountries)
{
  var quCities = from city
                 in cities
                 where city.countryID == country.Id
                 select city
  //display cities
  foreach (var city in quCities)
    Console.WriteLine(city.Name " in " country.Name);
}
```